# Average aggregation not available in DataFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I just need a simple math. mean over my `PCollection<Integer>` as aggregator while I process my pipeline.

I found `com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Mean.MeanFn` but it is package-private?!
Is there a reason for this? Marking it as `public` seems to work as I would assume it:

```
Aggregator<Long, Double> averageAge = createAggregator("Average age", new Mean.MeanFn<Integer>());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not support mean *aggregators* well enough in our monitoring tools currently, which is why the MeanFn is package-private (i.e. even if it was public, you wouldn't get much use out of it - right now we only use some mean aggregators for internal purposes).

However, you can use the [Mean *transform*](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Mean) to get a PCollection containing the mean as a single element:

```
PCollection<Double> meanAge = ages.apply(Mean.<Long>globally());
```

Comment: Don't like to have a side output just to get the value but will go with that route for the moment.